# Export value from asynchronous function in js.node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a list that is declared outside of the function and is added to inside the fileActions function. After my code is done running I would like to export the list in modules.exports. If I output the list under file2.on('finish', function() I get the result that I want. My problem is that I don't know how to get the list out of the asynchronous function and into modules.exports.

```
function getFile(){
    let file = fs.createWriteStream(getPath()+"file.json");
    request = https.get("https://fileLocation.com/file.json", function(response) {   
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
            fileActions();
            file.close();
        })
    });
}
```

The block of code will be inside a method map and it will be exported from

```
module.exports = {
    call: function (method, param, response) {

        if (methodMap[method]) {
            const result = methodMap[method](param, response);
            omnis_calls.sendResponse(result, response);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            throw Error("Method '" + method + "' does not exist");
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: I suspect you wouldn't export the *result* per se, but would instead export the `getFile` function which itself would return `request`.  (And within the response handler return the result.)  So the export is effectively a function returning a promise.  It would be up to consuming code to respond to the result of the promise.

Comment: Export a promise and use it in other file.